# Swift: Creating a function to edit UILabel settings

Tags: ios, swift, function, uilabel

I'm trying to use a function so I can efficiently change the settings of many UILabels at once. I'm trying to treat the label as a variable to show what I want to do. How could I achieve this?

```
func colorBlock(label: UILabel) {
     self.label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.75)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `self`:

```
func colorBlock(label: UILabel) {
     label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.75)
}
```

because `label` in this code is a function parameter and `self.label` is a property of a class this function belongs to.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was this simple. Thanks.